# How to ensure that 'gamerule keepInventory true' is persistent across server restarts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I'm running a bukkit Minecraft server.

I want to ensure that `gamerule keepInventory true` is persistent across server restarts.

Is this standard behaviour once I've set it on a world using the command, or do I need to provide some kind of configuration for this so that it is applied after restarts?

Further – is there some way I can configuring the server so that `gamerule` overrides are applied when new worlds are created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set a game rule it will persist through reboots, I have doFireTick set to false on my server and it persists over reboots, as far as I know there is no way to configure it so that any new world created will already have commands set.

Comment: Nice one. It's good enough for me if it persists over restarts. I'm not planning on spinning up worlds automatically and having them configured as I want. Not yet, anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

The servers I have been on have always had a button that you had to push in order for keep inventory to stay on. (I had to push the button every time I got on the server. The button was connected to a command block.)